# HTML and javascript colab

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an application with the LoL (league of legends) api.
Currently I'm having trouble with my input. First I made an `inputbox` and `submitbutton` in JavaScript and wrote some code so I could use it.

```
var inputbox = document.createElement("input");
inputbox.type = "input";
document.body.appendChild(inputbox);

var button = document.createElement("input")
button.type = "button";
button.value = "Press me!";
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Afterwards I used this code to use the input value.

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  LookUpSummonerInformation(inputbox.value);
});
```

My question is how can I put this into my index.html instead of my js file.
I can't use a form to do it as it will probably be a single page application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put your code between <script></script> tag!

Comment: Why not just write the html? And you can put the js code in between `<script>` tags or `<script src="path/to/sctript.js"></script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>LoL Thing</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type='input' id='lol-input'></input>
    <button onclick='do_the_thing();'>Press me!</button>

    <script>
      function do_the_thing() {
        var inputbox = document.querySelector('#lol-input');
        LookUpSummonerInformation(inputbox.value);
      }
    </script>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Here's a simple example of how you would mix the JS with HTML.

Comment: This seems like a good idea, however how can i include my script file (lol.js)  if the script tag is already used?

Comment: Edit: tested this and i still could include the file.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are looking for something like this

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <script>
      document.onload = function(){
        var inputbox = document.createElement("input");
        inputbox.type = "input";
        document.body.appendChild(inputbox);

        var button = document.createElement("input")
        button.type = "button";
        button.value = "Press me!";
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            LookUpSummonerInformation(inputbox.value);
        });
        document.body.appendChild(button);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always include JavaScript code using a `<script>` tag in the body of your html document.

Eg:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Head code here -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      // Your JavaScript code goes here
    </script>
    <!-- Remaining body code here -->
  </body>
<html>
```

**Alternatively**

You can link javascript to your index file also using a `<script>` tag.

Eg:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Head code here -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="path_to_your_js_file"></script>
    <!-- Remaining body code here -->
  </body>
<html>
```